# Run a volatile RDS Postgres function as a background process after client disconnects

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a Postgres 13.10 function, *check_jobs*, hosted on an RDS database that needs to be run every 5 minutes. Its purpose is to monitor a job queue (i.e. rows in a table with a 'pending' status), and depending on the current database load, potentially call another function, *update_tables*, that will perform inserts and updates into other tables.

The function called by *check_jobs* is typically long-running, taking up to an hour to complete. My goal is to call *check_jobs* from a Lambda function and have *check_jobs* call *update_tables* to run as a background process on the server, while *check_jobs* then returns and the client Lambda disconnects from the database.

I know that typical Postgres behaviour is for the server to terminate a running query if the client disconnects before the query has completed. I've investigated various options for running a db function as a background process but none of them seem to be suitable for my use case (my summaries are given below).

Background Worker Processes
(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bgworker.html)
Difficult to set up given that our Postgres is hosted in RDS. Uses C modules, which give unrestricted access to memory; PostgreSQL doc issues a security warning.

pg_cron
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL_pg_cron.html)
Difficult to set up given that our Postgres is hosted in RDS. Not really the right tool as it is designed for maintenance jobs triggered by a Cron process.

pg_background
(https://github.com/vibhorkum/pg_background)
Unofficial PG extension. Difficult to set up given that our Postgres is hosted in RDS.

dblink_send_query
(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-send-query.html)
Can run SELECT queries and STABLE function calls to completion after disconnecting, but cannot run VOLATILE functions (e.g. those that contain inserts or updates) after disconnecting.

Does anyone know of a suitable solution for my use case?

Comment: EventBridge could be of help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html